# Passing the returned stacked output to jax.lax.scan

Tags: python, jax

I wish to pass on the returned stacked values from the jax.lax.scan back to one of its arguments. Is it possible to do so? For example:

```
from jax import lax


def cumsum(res, el):
    """
    - `res`: The result from the previous loop.
    - `el`: The current array element.
    """
    v, u = res
    print(u)
    v = v + el
    return (v,u),v  # ("carryover", "accumulated")


result_init = 0
result = []

(final,use), result = lax.scan(cumsum, (result_init,result), a)
```

In the above code, I want to extract the cumulated res values during the runtime and pass it back. Thus, I have passed the result as an argument in the lax function, but it always prints an empty list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no built-in way to access the "current state" of the accumulated values in the course of a `scan` operation: in particular, the current state will be a dynamically-shaped array (it will have size 0 in the first iteration, size 1 in the second, etc.) and `scan`, like other JAX transformations and higher-order functions, requires static shapes.

But you could do something similar by passing along an array that you manually update. It might look something like this:

```py
from jax import lax
import jax.numpy as jnp
from jax import debug

def cumsum(carry, el):
    i, v, running_result = carry
    v = v + el
    running_result = running_result.at[i].set(v)
    debug.print("iteration {}: running_result={}", i, running_result)
    return (i + 1, v, running_result), v

a = jnp.arange(5)
running_result = jnp.zeros_like(a)
(i, v, running_result), result = lax.scan(cumsum, (0, 0, running_result), a)

print("\nfinal running result:", running_result)
print("final result:", result)
```

```
iteration 0: running_result=[0 0 0 0 0]
iteration 1: running_result=[0 1 0 0 0]
iteration 2: running_result=[0 1 3 0 0]
iteration 3: running_result=[0 1 3 6 0]
iteration 4: running_result=[ 0  1  3  6 10]

final running result: [ 0  1  3  6 10]
final result: [ 0  1  3  6 10]
```

Notice that I used `jax.debug.print` to print the intermediate results, because this function is traced and compiled.

Comment: Is it possible to use the array that stores these tracers for further calculations/ operations inside the function itself?

Comment: Yes, it’s a normal array that can be used in operations like any other array